Gauss-Seidel not converging
I'm an eletrical engineer student and just had a numerical methods test. The professor gave us a linear system of equations, that I think is impossible to solve using Gauss-Seidel. He didn't explain the convergence criteria very well. The system was:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
32 & 47 & 0\\
0 & 47 & 32
\end{bmatrix} *
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
9 \\
9
\end{bmatrix}$$
I know this system can be converted in a 2x2 matrix (that converges with Gauss-Seidel), but he explicitly wanted us to use the 3x3. I tried to manipulate the matrix using operations like sum of lines, switching lines or columns, but nothing worked. After a lot of people had trouble with the problem, he said that is converges.
